# Symfony - don't require embedded form fields

Tags: symfony

I have a symfony form for a client with fields that only an admin can edit. But the client can edit some fields as well. However, I'm not using the same form but different one that has fields only for the client.

```
// ClientType
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name', TextType::class, ['required' => true])
        ->add('link', UrlType::class, ['required' => false])
        ...
```

And so on with other fields. As a requirement I have to create a separate form with other fields the client and some fields from his own entity from the form above.

```
// CustomClientType
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('someField', TextType::class, ['required' => true])
        ->add('client', ClientType::class)
        ...
```

and in my twig.

```
...
{{ form_widget(form.client.link) }}
...
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

so not to render unwanted fields. The CustomClientType has an entity of its own. When I submit the custom form I get errors for the required fields of the embedded form. So the question is how can I ignore the unrendered fields from the embedded form without changing them in the Client entity? Only the rendered fields of the embedded form should be updated in the entity.

Using Symfony 2.8 with plans to update to 3.4 later this year.

Comment: set `mapped` to false on unrequired fields

Comment: I knew I was missing some simple solution... Thanks, this works. The only setback is that I have to set the value for those fields when rendering the embedded form by itself.

Comment: after some testing I found that this solution does not work as after submitting the CustomClientType form all other fields are set to null in the ClientType form and the entity is also updated with null

Comment: you have to actuallly call the data manually, it won't be got automatically due to it being unmapped

Comment: Indeed, an since there are a lot of fields in the embedded form and I only need a few of them in the other one I'll create new unmapped fields and get the data for them manually. Will leave this open in case of a cleaner solution. Thanks